# Devise authentication from different application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, post, heroku, devise

I have a perfectly working rails application including devise authentication.

I created a second separated rails application for the public website, which runs as separate heroku application.

The problem is: It should be possible to sign up and sign in to the main application using forms in the public website.

How is it possible to authenticate users using devise through a form in a different application? What's the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your applications use different subdomains but are under the same domain, [this article](https://github.com/fortuity/rails3-subdomain-devise/wiki/Tutorial-%28Walkthrough%29) might help.

And Chris Oliver took an approach to implement this in Rails 3.1 [here](http://excid3.com/blog/sharing-a-devise-user-session-across-subdomains-with-rails-3/)